# The volume of the region enclosed around the Y-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, image3d

The volume of the region enclosed by $x=y^{3}$, $x=0$, $y=2$, revolved around the Y-axis is?

My question is, how would that solid be represented?

Comment: Didn't you already accept an answer to this question?

Comment: Incidentally, if you accept an answer I think you should also upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[x^(1/3), {x, 0, 2},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "z", "y"}]
```

[image]